# What resources are there for learning Lingua Franca Nova (LFN)?

Tags: resource-request, constructed-languages

I find [Lingua Franca Nova](http://elefen.org/) to be one of the more interesting [constructed languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language) because of its extreme grammatical simplicity. It's almost like Chinese in its [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_language) nature but with Romance-based vocabulary.

Are there resources, outside of what's on the website, for learning to read and speak this language?

Comment: I believe that there is an LFN version of *Alice in Wonderland* out there.

Answer (score 2):

Discord has a server called “La tavera de elefen”. Tandem and, maybe, HelloTalk has a few Lingua Franca Nova speakers.

Comment: Would you mind providing some links to these resources, please?